# How to grab inner text from selected Node to Next Node

Tags: c#, vb.net, xpath

In C#/VB, I want to use xpath, I would like to collect `inner.Text` from `w:fldChar[@fldCharType='begin']` to next `w:fldChar`.

My XML is

```
<w:r>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:instrText xml:space="preserve">GUID=01f8513e-c4e1-41c2-9c7b-0c9a8be5f9e6
  </w:instrText>
</w:r>
<w:r>
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="end"/>
</w:r>
```

and

```
<w:r w:rsidDel="001447B3">
  <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="begin"/>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidDel="001447B3">
   <w:delInstrText xml:space="preserve"> HYPERLINK "</w:delInstrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="00B0540E" w:rsidDel="001447B3">
  <w:delInstrText xml:space="preserve"> SummaryOfTable_200</w:delInstrText>
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidDel="001447B3">
  <w:delInstrText xml:space="preserve">4.htm"</w:delInstrText>  
</w:r>
<w:r w:rsidDel="001447B3">
   <w:fldChar w:fldCharType="separate"/>
</w:r>
```

I can't locate the exact tree structure like "parent.nextSiling" because the root node will very based on the content.

```
foreach (XmlElement aNode in loadXML.SelectNodes("//w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType='begin]", nsmgr))
{
   XmlAttribute newAttr = loadXML.CreateAttribute("FieldValue");

   newAttr.Value = //i like to get text from w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType='begin] to next w:fldChar;

   aNode.Attributes.Append(newAttr);
}
```

In XPath "following-sibling:fldChar" and "following::fldChar" have two different syntax but C# has only "NextSibling", it's doing only the sibling Level.

How do I get the inner text.

Comment: OMG! Please be **much** more carefull about formatting..

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want all nodes in between `w:fldChar` elements, right? You can do so by applying the conditions directly in XPath:

```
w:r[preceding::w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType="begin"]]][following::w:r[w:fldChar]]
```

If you do not want the `w:r` element but the child elements instead, you can simply add a child selector:

```
w:r[preceding::w:r[w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType="begin"]]][following::w:r[w:fldChar]]/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this task with your help!

```
foreach (XmlElement aNode in loadXML.SelectNodes("//w:fldChar[@w:fldCharType='begin']", nsmgr))
{
  int total = aNode.SelectNodes("following::w:r", nsmgr).Count - aNode.SelectNodes("following::w:fldChar/following::w:r", nsmgr).Count;
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
  {
    XmlAttribute newAttr = loadXML.CreateAttribute("FieldValue");
    sb.Append(aNode.SelectNodes("following::w:r", nsmgr).Item(i).InnerText);
    newAttr.Value = sb.ToString();
    aNode.Attributes.Append(newAttr);
  }
}
```